# Confused about storing data from this form

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I have been practising mysql and then I have came across an issue that I can't solve.
I am making a large form that will be able to store information from user in the database.
I have managed to make and store data from simple form fields like Name, Country, Age, Interest and etc using mysql and php.

I have a table called `users` in my database which have approximate 15 column for different data like Name, Country, Age etc.

Now I have added this from field to my from and confused about how to store data from this field.

Here is the img of my form ....

[image: see the pic]

Now if I create a column `emp_name` then how  am I going to store 1-4 values for each user with 5 fields each?

Even if I create a different table ex - `emp_history` then how to store data from this form for each user?

Comment: I think your looking for a one to many relationship?

Answer (score 1):

Your form should be like this:

```
<form name="xyz" method="post"> <table> <tr> <td>Emp name</td><td>country</td><td>position</td> </tr> <tr> <td> <input type="text" name="data[emp_name][]" value="" /> <input type="text" name="data[country][]" value="" /> <input type="text" name="data[position][]" value="" /> </td> </tr> <tr> <td> <input type="text" name="data[emp_name][]" value="" /> <input type="text" name="data[country][]" value="" /> <input type="text" name="data[position][]" value="" /> </td> </tr> <tr> <td> <input type="text" name="data[emp_name][]" value="" /> <input type="text" name="data[country][]" value="" /> <input type="text" name="data[position][]" value="" /> </td> </tr> </table>

when you post the form, you will get the value in php file like this:

$arr = $_POST['data']; $cnt = count($arr['emp_name']);

for($i=0; $i<$cnt; $i++) {
    $name = $arr['emp_name'][$i];   
    $country = $arr['country'][$i];   
    $position = $arr['position'][$i];   
    // insert sql
    $sql = insert into emp_table(name, country, position) values('".$name."', '".$country."', '".$position."'); }
```

Comment: well seems hard for beginners like me ... but bro skparwal do you have sample script or can you recommend any form processor script from where i could study the code ?

Comment: it is very simple. you just need to create the text elements in an array form. e.g <input type="text" name="data[]" />

Comment: check this link. may be this can help you. [php easy step](http://www.phpeasystep.com/mysql/10.html)

Comment: then will it hold 1-4 data in just one column ex- `emp_name` and what will it look like in the database row ? i am just little bit confused ... or can you refer any details guide or article to study more about this kind of scenarios ..

Comment: php easy step tutorial teaches the simple input and update query but the above table says.....each separate user will have separate employment histroy which will be submitted through row 1-4 and Employer's Name (all 4 of them) will go in one column called `emp_name`  .. Sorry it looks a bit complicated and messi... :{

Comment: [another example](http://www.shotdev.com/php/php-sql-server/php-sql-server-mssql-add-insert-multiple-record/)

Comment: OP, by doing this you would end up with an array of `$_POST` data, like so: `echo $_POST['emp_name'][0] // outputs "First name"`, then you would just loop through the data to add each row to the SQL database.

Answer (score 0):

Create two tables

tbl_more_detail  ( here you store all for info 1-4)

> id (PK)
>    emp_id
>    emp_name
>    emp_country
>    emp_position
>    emp_from
>    emp_to

tbl_emp_detail ( here you give reference to above ids, will have 4 rows with different detail_id)

> id(PK)
>   emp_id
>   detail_id ( FK Refer to `tbl_more_detail`.`id`)

NOTE: to prevent duplicate entry, create UNIQUE KEY INDEX on (emp_id, detail_id)

Comment: thx for the ans .. well the text fields of the Employer's Name,  Country , Position , etc will have the same name and id ?

Comment: save all data in `more_info`  add `emp_id` in that table too.

Answer (score 0):

First create a database table:

```
create table emp_table {
    id int(10) auto_increment primary key,
    emp_name varchar(100),
    country varchar(50),
    position varchar(50)
}
```

now create a php file that includes below code:

```
<h2>Insert new records</h2>
<form name="emp" method="post">
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td>Employee name</td>
    <td>Country</td>
    <td>Position</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="data[emp_name][]" value="" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="data[country][]" value="" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="data[position][]" value="" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="data[emp_name][]" value="" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="data[country][]" value="" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="data[position][]" value="" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="data[emp_name][]" value="" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="data[country][]" value="" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="data[position][]" value="" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="data[emp_name][]" value="" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="data[country][]" value="" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="data[position][]" value="" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

<?php
mysql_connect('localhost', 'dbuser', 'dbpassword');
mysql_select_db('db_name');

if(isset($_POST['data'])) {
    $cnt = $_POST['data']['emp_name'];

    for($i=0; $i<$cnt; $i++) {
        $name = $arr['emp_name'][$i];   
        $country = $arr['country'][$i];   
        $position = $arr['position'][$i];   
        // insert sql
        $sql = "insert into emp_table(name, country, position) values('".$name."', '".$country."', '".$position."')";
        mysql_query($sql);  
    }
}

?>
<br/><br/>
<h2>Existing Records</h2>
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td>Employee name</td>
    <td>Country</td>
    <td>Position</td>
</tr>
<?php
$str = '';
$objQuery = mysql_query('select * from emp_table');
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery))  
{
    $str .= '<tr>';
    $str .= '<td>'.$result['emp_name'].'</td><td>'.$result['country'].'</td><td>'.$result['position'].'</td>';
    $str .= '</tr>';
}
echo $str;
?>
</table>
```

Now run your application. You can see the result on the same page (with an existing records)

Comment: thank you very much for detailed ans .. your last submitted code almost solves the problem expect it stores blank value when i have added a form action , and a submit button to your code ....